# Save GAN generated images

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, generative-adversarial-network

I'm new to learning python. I saw a code on the Internet that saves the generated gan images. But I need these generated images to be saved to a folder in Google Coollaboratory (Colab). How do I do this?

```
def generate_and_save_images(model, epoch, test_input):
 predictions = model(test_input, training=False)
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))

 for i in range(predictions.shape[0]):
  plt.subplot(4, 4, i+1)
  plt.imshow(predictions[i, :, :, 0] * 127.5 + 127.5, cmap='gray')
  plt.imsave('image_at_epoch_{:04d}-{}.png'.format(epoch, i), predictions[i, :, :, 0] * 127.5 + 127.5, cmap='gray')
  plt.axis('off')

 plt.savefig('image_at_epoch_{:04d}.png'.format(epoch))
 plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `files` from `google.colab` library

```py
# Import files from google colab
from google.colab import files

def generate_and_save_images(model, epoch, test_input):
    predictions = model(test_input, training=False)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))

    for i in range(predictions.shape[0]):
    plt.subplot(4, 4, i+1)
    plt.imshow(predictions[i, :, :, 0] * 127.5 + 127.5, cmap='gray')
    plt.imsave('image_at_epoch_{:04d}-{}.png'.format(epoch, i), predictions[i, :, :, 0] * 127.5 + 127.5, cmap='gray')
    plt.axis('off')

    plt.savefig('folder_name/image_at_epoch_{:04d}.png'.format(epoch))

    # Saves the file
    files.download('folder_name/image_at_epoch_{:04d}.png'.format(epoch))

    plt.show()
```

Make sure the `plt.show` is called before the `files.dowload(..)`